# Images are stretching on my WordPress mobile theme for iPhone

Tags: wordpress

I have installed an iPhone-friendly mobile theme for my WordPress-based blog http://www.windowswave.com.

The blog post images appear fine on desktop browsers, but they appear stretched on the iPhone.

I'm curious if anyone knows a solution for this issue. I'd greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use CSS to add `height: auto !important;` to your blog post images.  What's happening is the mobile theme is restricting the image width to 100% of the screen width, but not adjusting the height accordingly.

Comment: If you're using a browser with an inspector, right click the blog image and Inspect it to see what I mean.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks a bunch! I changed 

`img { max-width:100% !important; }` 

to

`img { max-width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}`

And it works! Woohoo!

Comment: No problem, glad you've got it straightened out. Unfortunately when WordPress prints out images it embeds the width and height into the img tag, and it makes staying responsive a little bit trickier.

Comment: Yeah, thanks again! My mobile site looks much better now. Now I'm going to get some sleep and spend Sunday producing some actual content (not filler posts!). Time to get this site on the roll! Only issue I have left is the blog post titles appear much smaller on IE 6, 7 and 8. Maybe you know a solution for that too?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine in visual editing by changing picture from custom to original, which automatically changed height to auto.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35134249)